# Hide child package for dokka documentation

Tags: kotlin, documentation, kotlin-dokka

im want make doc just for main package so i have package with name **com.exam.device**, but doc from dokka also generate for child package ex: **com.exam.device.utils**, **com.exam.device.utils.breakdown**, **com.exam.device.list**. i need expose doc for main package only, i try this config but doesnt give what i wanted

```
dokkaHtml.configure {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        perPackageOption {
            matchingRegex.set("utils")
            suppress.set(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it Kotlin or Java project?